# Private vs Static constructors in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, static-constructor, private-constructor

I searched for this a lot, but none of the answers are clear (at-least for me!). Now I'm putting this question in SO, as I believe I can't get a more clarified answer anywhere else.

When should I use a private/static constructor in my class?

I'm fed up of usual answers, so please help me with some real-time examples and advantages/disadvantages of using these constructors.

Comment: Private constructor - if you don't want your object to be constructable from outside of current class. Static constructor - if you need to initialize the static class' state.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Static constructors: used for initialising static members.

Private constructors: used when you only want a class to be instantiated from within its own code (typically in a static method).  For example:

```
public class Thing
{
    static int Number;

    static Thing()
    {
        Number = 42; // This will only be called once, no matter how many instances of the class are created
    }

    // This method is the only means for external code to get a new Thing
    public static Thing GetNewThing()
    {
        return new Thing();
    }

    // This constructor can only be called from within the class.
    private Thing()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You can implement the factory pattern this way - i.e. if you have business objects which need to be in a certain 'state' but you want to prevent 3rd parties/other devs from initialising them using the public constructor, you can make the constructor private, and provide a set of factory methods to create/get the objects. This way they can't get a 'blank' stateless object by constructor (unless they really want to e.g. reflection)

Comment: Static constructor can also be used to invoke private constructor, which in turn instantiate private static member of containing class type. Than static function/property can just return this member, so there is always only one instance of such object - a singleton.

Answer (score 8):

> When should I use a private constructor in my class?

When you want a constructor, but don't want to expose it to the world. This could be because you have a factory method that calls the constructor (after validation), or because that constructor is called by ctor-chaining (i.e. `public Foo(string) : this() { ...}`).

Additionally, note that reflection code is often able to use a private constructor - for example serialization or ORM libraries.

Also, in early C# compilers, when you are writing what would now be a `static` class - having a private constructor was the only way of making it appear uncreatable.

> When should I use a static constructor in my class?

When you need to initialize some static state prior to that state being accessed by instances or static methods.

Answer (score 3):

Static constructor is used to intialize the static members of the class and is called when the first instance of the class is created or a static member is accessed for the first time.

Private constructor is used if you have overloads of the constructor, and some of them should only be used by the other constructors